# get Lexmark Z515 running on Linux

Tags: linux, drivers, printer

Following [this tutorial](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=49714) I was able to intall [this driver here](http://forumubuntusoftware.info/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=3782) in Crunchbang Linux 11. As expected, it didn't work. Lexmark itself offers a driver for OS X and that was it. I've tried something similar on a Windows Installation (Test Version of "Server 2008), which lead to a complete freeze of the system.

**Question**: What would be a good approach to get a Lexmark Z515 Printer, connected to the machine via USB, running on Linux?